# Starting SublimeREPL for Scheme gives OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')

Tags: configuration, scheme, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I've been trying to use SublimeREPL to run an interactive interpreter of Scheme, but I keep getting the error message "OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')". I know it's likely a file path issue in Main.sublime-menu, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Not sure if I'm missing something obvious or what. Any help would be appreciated! Here is the config file that I have in SublimeREPL/config/Scheme (unchanged since install):

```
[
 {
    "id": "tools",
    "children":
    [{
        "caption": "SublimeREPL",
        "mnemonic": "r",
        "id": "SublimeREPL",
        "children":
        [
            {"caption": "Scheme",
             "id": "Scheme",

             "children":[
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Scheme",
                 "id": "repl_scheme",
                 "mnemonic": "r",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "external_id": "scheme",
                    "cmd": {"linux": ["scheme"],
                            "osx": ["scheme"],
                            "windows": ["scheme"]},
                    "soft_quit": "\nexit\n",
                    "cwd": "$folder",
                    "cmd_postfix": "\n",
                    "extend_env": {"INSIDE_EMACS": "1"},
                    "syntax": "Packages/sublime-scheme-syntax/Scheme.tmLanguage"
                    }
                },
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Gauche",
                 "id": "repl_gauche",
                 "mnemonic": "r",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "external_id": "gauche",
                    "cmd": {"linux": ["gosh", "-i"],
                            "osx": ["gosh", "-i"],
                            "windows": ["gosh", "-i"]},
                    "soft_quit": "\n(exit)\n",
                    "cwd": "$folder",
                    "cmd_postfix": "\n",
                    "extend_env": {"INSIDE_EMACS": "1"},
                    "syntax": "Packages/Gauche/Gauche.tmLanguage"
                    }
                },
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Petite Chez Scheme",
                 "id": "repl_petite",
                 "mnemonic": "r",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "external_id": "petite",
                    "cmd": {"linux": ["petite"],
                            "osx": ["petite"],
                            "windows": ["petite"]},
                    "soft_quit": "\n(exit)\n",
                    "cwd": "$folder",
                    "cmd_postfix": "\n",
                    "extend_env": {"INSIDE_EMACS": "1"},
                    "syntax": "Packages/sublime-scheme-syntax/Scheme.tmLanguage"
                    }
                }
            ]}
        ]
    }]
}
]
```

Comment: what OS are you using, and what is the path to `scheme` on your system? If you are running OS X/Linux, open a command prompt any type `which scheme` to find out.

Comment: Right, I should have stated that. I am using OS X 10.8.5. I tried the command 'which scheme', but it didn't show anything...

Comment: Ok, it looks like the Scheme folder path is /Users/Jerridan/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have scheme installed on your system. The `/Users/Jerridan/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Scheme` directory is just the Scheme package for Sublime - syntax highlighting, completions, etc. It doesn't contain the actual Scheme interpreter. There appear to be several scheme versions available online, so do some research and install the one that would fit your needs.

Once installed, note the path to the interpreter. If you're still getting the No Such File or Directory error, edit the `"cmd"` section of the `Main.sublime-menu` file you posted to add the full path. For example, if you install Petite Chez Scheme and `which petite` returns `/usr/local/bin/petite`, then add that to the `"osx"` section of the `"cmd"`:

```
"osx": ["/usr/local/bin/petite"],
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I definitely thought the package included an interpreter. It's working now!